# Java jFrame toBack() and focusable

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, jtextfield

I got a Jframe which has a JTextField and a JButton which opens a popup. The popup has to be always in front of the JFrame. 
Is it possible to write on the JTextField while the popup is still in front of the JFrame?

Comment: *" Is it possible to write on the JTextField while the popup is still in front of the JFrame?"* - If the "popup" isn't a "modal" dialog, then, yes

Comment: If it is modal it wont work, right?

Comment: If it's a modal based window, then, no, it won't work.  By could use `JFrame` as the popup and set it as "always on top", then it won't matter

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still modify the contents inside an object.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: JTextField f = new JTextField(); f.setText("text");

Comment: Sorry, I meant writing to the JTextField with your keyboard.  If I use toBack() the JTextField wont be focusable. Sorry its hard for me to describe my problem :)

Comment: Can you provide any code or screenshot? Any would be appreciated!

Comment: No, you cannot enter (type) anything in the text field if the popup is modal. That is the definition of "modal": you can only interact with that popup. If you make the popup modeless, then you can type into the text field. Note that you can make a modeless dialog stay on top using `dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`